# Joomla Wiki Integration

Tags: extensions

I am looking for free extension which would provide me with all the functionality of a wiki. I would like it to be as close to the Wikipedia page if possible.

Can anyone suggest the best way to go about this. would it be installing a wiki separately, then incorporating a plugin, or are there any good extensions out there?

Comment: Just in case this isn't the place for my question, i apologise. If it isn't the correct place, i will remove my question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually going to answer this as I did not find any concrete solutions.

You have 2 options here:

#### Option 1:

Download and install [Media Wiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) on a **sub-domain**. It's a standalone system which looks exactly like Wikipedia.

#### Option 2:

Use an FAQ extension, such as [Freestyle FAQs](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/directory-a-documentation/faq/freestyle-faqs). More extensions can be found under the [FAQ category](http://extensions.joomla.org/tags/faq) on the Joomla Extensions Directory.

#### Option 3:

Don't use an extension or standalone system at all, but instead make full use of Joomla articles. You can create a category, tags and have you own menu items dedicated to your Wiki content. It will take a little longer to setup than an FAQ extension probably, however it means you don't add unnecessary bulk to your site.

Comment: Similar to option3, it could a CCK extension dedicated for his wiki - let's say k2, and keep joomla articles for the main content of his site - so it will be a bit cleaner in the backend - plus he could have any custom extra fields he might need for the wiki pages.

Comment: If you choose option 1 and install a separate media wiki site, how do you integrate this into Joomla pages? Presumably you want the wiki pages to show up as content in the Joomla site, correct?

Comment: @Demis you can use an iframe or if you Google `mediawiki joomla`, there will probably be some integrations out there

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Lodder's Option3, it could be a **CCK extension** dedicated for your wiki content, and keep the Joomla core articles for the rest content of your site - so it will be a bit cleaner in the backend - plus you could have any custom extra fields or functionality you might need for the wiki pages.

If you do a search for [**Joomla CCKs**](https://www.google.gr/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=joomla%20cck&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=KQEUVpDpBNKCoQebja3ACg) you will find a lot of options.

Of course **[K2](http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/free/k2)** by JoomlaWorks is a an option and generally is quite easy to get familiar with it.

For more advanced things, you could look for something like **[Fabrik](http://fabrikar.com)** or **[Cobalt](http://www.mintjoomla.com/joomla-components/cobalt.html)**.